# TSQL Emailing data field containing URL didn't work

Tags: html, t-sql

I am trying to email data field containing URL.  What am I doing wrong.  Below is my code:
If I comment out the URL field [URL_Field] it works fine.  Right now with the [URL_Field] the email sends but nothing comes through my email inbox.

```
DECLARE
@EmailSubject VARCHAR(100),
@TextTitle VARCHAR(100),
@TableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Profile_name VARCHAR(100) = 'TstDBMail',  
@Recipients VARCHAR(2000) = 'name@company.com', 
@startdate DATETIME, 
@enddate DATETIME

SET @EmailSubject = 'ALERT: on'''+@@SERVERNAME +'''' 
SET @TextTitle = 'Alert on ' + @@SERVERNAME +'.'

SET @TableHTML =
'<html>'+
'<head><style>'+
-- Data cells styles font size
'td {border:1px solid #ddd;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt}'+
'</style></head>'+
'<body>'+
-- Text Title style
'<div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13pt; font-family:calibri;">' + @TextTitle +'</div>' +
-- Color and columns names
'<div style="font-family:Calibri; "><table>'+'<tr bgcolor="red">'+
    '<td align=left><font face="calibri" color=White><b>customer_id</b></font></td>'+  
    '<td align=left><font face="calibri" color=White><b>timestamp_utc</b></font></td>'+ 
    '<td align=left><font face="calibri" color=White><b>URL_Field</b></font></td>'+ 
'</tr></div>'
-----------------------------------------------------------
----- Querying Data --------
-----------------------------------------------------------
SELECT @Body =(SELECT top 1
                   td = customer_id  
                  ,td = timestamp_utc     
                  ,td =  URL_Field 
               FROM LAMN_Temp with (nolock)
               FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS)

SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '<td>', '<td align=left><font face="calibri">')
SET @TableHTML = @TableHTML + @Body + '</table></div></body></html>'
SET @TableHTML = '<div style="color:Black; font-size:8pt; font-family:Calibri; width:auto;">' + @TableHTML + '</div>'
-------------------------------
----- Sending email -----------
-------------------------------
IF(@Body IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@Profile_name = @Profile_name,
@Recipients = @Recipients ,
@Body = @TableHTML,
@Subject = @EmailSubject,
@Body_format = 'HTML'
END;
```

Comment: HTML is not XML. You cannot process HTML which does not conform to XHTML using T-SQL's `XML` functionality. Additionally, SQL Server's email functionality is really meant for plaintext alerts, not rich HTML emails. You should use an out-of-proc service for this.

Comment: Also, how have you configured SQL Mail? Is your SMTP server configured correctly?

Comment: Yep, SQL Mail is configured and working fine.  I get emails when I remove the URL field.  So it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` appended to any string value results in `NULL`, rather than appending an empty string. So if you have **any** missing values for the  `URL_Field`, the entire `@Body` will end up as `NULL`. This fails the `IF` check and won't send email.

You can probably fix it by changing this:

```
,td =  URL_Field
```

To this:

```
,td =  coalesce(URL_Field,'')
```

This other way this might happen is if `URL_Field` adds enough size to the variable it overflows.

But I agree with the comment that this is a misuse of the SQL mail feature. You'll have much less pain and get much better results using a real mail processing service. It'll probably also cost less in the long run if you're properly accounting for your time spent maintaining this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I tried a few things and this is the only option that worked so far:

`td =   REPLACE(URL_Field, '/', '_')`
although this changes the data, but at least it's clear to me now what's breaking my code.

Any other suggestions would appreciated. Thanks.